# Inner block of a code is getting executed after the first block in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

According to this "1" was to be printed first and then "2". BUt it is giving a wrong output.

```
fs.readdir("./my_stocks", (err, files) => {
    for(each in files){
        var file=files[each];
        if(file!='portfolio.js'){
            var fn="./my_stocks/"+file;
            fs.readFile(fn,(err,data)=>{
                var arr=data.toString().split('\n');
                console.log(1);
                fs.appendFile("./my_stocks/portfolio.js",JSON.stringify(stock_detail),(err)=>{
                    if(err) throw err;
                });
            });
            console.log(2)
        }
    }
});
```

output:

> 2
> 2
> 1
> 1

Answer (score 0):

The "inner block" is a callback to the `fs.readFile` statement. What happens is

1. `fs.readFile` is executed and starts an *asynchronous* reading of the file.
2. The next statement is executed, outputting a "2".
3. Steps 1 and 2 are repeated for each file in the directory, so that two "2"'s are outputted altogether.
4. Later, when the reading of a file is completed, the "inner block" is executed, outputting a "1".
5. Since two files are being read altogether, step 4 is executed twice and two "1"'s are output. But the first "1" being output does not necessarily belong to the first file being read, because a shorter file may have finished reading before a longer one, even if it started later.

If you want to avoid such asynchronousness, you can use [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) (and also `fs.readdirSync`). But this will slow down the overall execution, because files are then read one after the other, not in parallel. If the order of the entries in your `portfolio.js` does not matter, asynchronousness is therefore preferable.

Note, however, that appending several `stock_details` to one `portfolio.js` does not make valid Javascript overall:

```js
{"Stock 1":100}{"Stock 2":200}
```

Assuming that every file contains lines such as

```
A: 1
B: 2
```

(without a final newline), you can read and process them asynchronously with the "[promises flavor](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_promise_example)" of the `fs` package:

```js
const fs = require("fs/promises");
fs.readdir("./my_stocks")
.then(function(files) {
  var promises = [];
  for(each in files){
    var file=files[each];
    if(file!='portfolio.js'){
      var fn="./my_stocks/"+file;
      promises.push(fs.readFile(fn)
        .then(data => data.toString().split('\n')));
    }
  }
  return Promise.all(promises);
})
.then(portfolio => fs.writeFile("./my_stocks/portfolio.js", JSON.stringify(portfolio)));
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a json file that has the details of all the stock-related files in `./my_stock/`. So I'm getting an empty file every time I execute it.

Is `fs.readFileSync()` a good practice?
@Heiko

Comment: Synchronous execution is not good practice (for large files), because it blocks the Javascript thread. See my edited answer for a solution using asynchronous execution.