# How to store mysql query result to a global varibale in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am beginner to node and I am trying to get the result of mysql query in to a global varible. How can I do that? I want to access that value for later use.Please help

Here is what I have tried.

```js
var last_id ='';    
function callback(val){
   last_id =val;
}
```

```js
var sesion_sql = "INSERT INTO session_waterfall (event, step,campaign_id,session_id,timestamp,elapsed) VALUES ('gfdgdfgfd', ' 2',' 23','1234','0','0')";
  connection.query(sesion_sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    callback(20);
  });
});

 console.log(last_id);
```

Comment: You didn't specify why your code does not produce the expected result. But I assume the problem is that `console.log(last_id)` is executed *synchronously*, before the `callback(20)`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034853/inner-block-of-a-code-is-getting-executed-after-the-first-block-in-node-js

Comment: i am not getting what is the problem, I just want to assign the result to a global varible for later use. could you please help?

Comment: You "use" the global variable (in `console.log(last_id)`) *before* it is assigned (in `callback(20)`). This is because the assignment happens asynchronously whereas the use happens synchronously.

Comment: how do I assign the varible synchronously then?

Comment: You cannot (and probably don't want), because an SQL query is inherently asynchronous. Your question cannot be answered satisfactorily without more context: What do you mean by "later use"? You seem to have two events: one triggers the SQL query and writes the `last_id`, and the other triggers something which wants to access the `last_id`. What are these events? Are how will your code react if there are thousands of pairs of such events going on in parallel (imagine thousands of users accessing your web page)? Do they all share the same `last_id`?

Comment: yes for now all will access last_id. Thanks